# how to remove .com, .org,.co.uk,.co.us using regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I am working on regular expression and right now I am having problem as I am not able to remove the .com, .net, .co.uk kind of extensions from the url that is for example I have a url like

```
url = subdomain.domain.com or domain.co.uk or domain.net
```

after using regular expression I need the output to be only **domain**..so can someone help me out with this.

Comment: Susan, where's the regular expression you've tried? It doesn't work because there's no code!

Comment: Does it really have to be a regular expression? While they can be a wonderful tool they also have some flaws: they require a measure of regularity in the strings they process and deal with. Given that a TLD can follow the first, second, third `.` character, be composed of two, three, four or five characters (including the second period in `'.co.uk'`), the regularity is limited, and rife with edge cases (especially given that [custom TLDs are now a thing](http://blog.icann.org/2012/01/icann-stands-ready-for-new-gtld-launch/)).

Comment: It is useless to do this with custom TLD (which is already implemented and many domains sold) and internationalized TLD (which is being implemented). Is there any reason why you have to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
//match domain name (with HTTP)
var domainRegex = /(.*?)[^w{3}.]([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,65}[a-zA-Z0-9])?.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}/igm; 
//match domain name (www. only) 
var domainRegex = /[^w{3}.]([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,65}[a-zA-Z0-9])?.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}/igm; 
//match domain name (alternative)
var domainRegex = /(.*?).(com|net|org|info|coop|int|com.au|co.uk|org.uk|ac.uk|)/igm; 
//match sub domains: www, dev, int, stage, int.travel, stage.travel
var subDomainRegex = /(http://|https://)?(www.|dev.)?(int.|stage.)?(travel.)?(.*)+?/igm;
```

Source: [SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-basic-regex-selector-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.*([^\.]+)(com|net|org|info|coop|int|co\.uk|org\.uk|ac\.uk|uk|__and so on__)$
```

or

> /^(?:www.)?(.*?).(?:com|au.uk|co.in)$/

Comment: can you give me the whole statement if you dont mind